# opendj setup takes 2+ minutes to complete

Tags: opendj

Is there any reason why my opendj takes more than 2 minutes to complete init setup ?

the setup command I'm using is like:
 setup --cli -p 1389 --baseDN $BASE_DN -h localhost --rootUserDN "${OPENDJ_DIR_MANAGER}" --rootUserPassword "${OPENDJ_DIR_MANAGER_PW}" --addBaseEntry --acceptLicense --no-prompt --verbose

find below log:

[INFO]  [2017-01-03T11:29:15+0000] Running setup.sh
[INFO]  [2017-01-03T11:29:15+0000] Setting up default OpenDJ instance

See /tmp/opendj-setup-7089778767611065994.log for a detailed log of this
operation.

Configuring Directory Server ..... Done.

---

Creating Base Entry dc=example,dc=com ..... Done.

---

Starting Directory Server:
[03/Jan/2017:11:31:14 +0000] category=CORE severity=NOTICE
msgID=org.opends.messages.core.134 msg=OpenDJ 3.0.1-SNAPSHOT (build
20161229142204, revision number 1050009bd82b5c5f51f5d38b146243700ca01044)
starting up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenDJ is a Java based product. You might want to check the JVM and its default memory settings. Another option is DNS (OpenDJ does a reverse lookup at startup).

Comment: I am trying to run opendj in docker/k8s. Is there an official docker image?

Comment: what do you mean by reverse lookup? i setup with -h localhost.

Comment: There is no official image yet. As for reverse lookup, I had not realized you used -h localhost. I remembered that some people had issues with slow startup and it was tied to naming service misconfigured and DNS lookup timing out.